# CodenameOne Streaming from PLS file?

Tags: java, streaming, codenameone

I have been working on a radio app in CodenameOne. I first did the podcast streaming which works fine and uses `MediaManager.createMedia(url, false);`

The files from the podcasts are all mp3s. I tried using the same method to stream a .pls file and when that didn't work I tried streaming the `http://0.0.0.0:8080` (example `http://hostname:port`) url as well and it didn't work either. I am using Eclipse and not getting any crashes but no output either.

NOTE:
I am able to get the stream on the Android API using the `MediaPlayer`'s `mp.setDataSource(url)` method.

Answer (score 0):

We use the native OS platform for streaming and the one in Java/JavaFX is pretty basic (doesn't even support https). Its very likely that this will work on Android and possibly iOS despite not working in the simulator. However, I don't have specific experience with that specific streaming format.